# In R, use stringr to extract values from a string that are within [] brackets

Tags: r, regex, stringr

```
fetch_url = "https://www.website.com?splitArr=[43]&splitArrPitch=&position=P&statType=player&startDate=2023-03-28&endDate=2023-04-11&players=&filter=&groupBy=season"
start_date <- stringr::str_extract(fetch_url, "(?<=startDate=)[^&]+")
end_date <- stringr::str_extract(fetch_url, "(?<=endDate=)[^&]+")
stat_type <- stringr::str_extract(fetch_url, "(?<=statType=)[^&]+")
split_arr <- stringr::str_extract(fetch_url, "(?<=splitArr\\[)[^]]+")
```

We are successfully able to extract `start_date`, `end_date`, and `stat_type` from this string, however we are struggling to get the `'43'` for `split_arr`. How can we update the code for this?

Alternatively, for a fetch_url such as `https://www.website.com?splitArr=&splitArrPitch=&position=P&statType=player&startDate=2023-03-28&endDate=&players=&filter=&groupBy=season` as a second example, this should return an empty string `''` for `split_arr` as well as for `end_date`.

We are close as we've gotten the first 3 variables, but the `[]` brackets around splitArr is making this variable harder to grab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `=` before the `[` - instead of the regex lookarounds, we can also capture (`(...)`) and specify the capture group in `group`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(fetch_url, "splitArr=\\[(\\d+)", group = 1)
[1] "43"
```

Comment: do I have an older version of `stringr`? I receive `unused argument (group = 1)`. I am using 1.4.0

Comment: @Canovice I used `1.5.0`

Comment: `Error in `stop_vctrs()`: ! Input must be a vector, not an environment.` is my new error after ugprading. I've made this worse by upgrading to 1.5.0, I think because my R version is below 4.1.2, as I get the warning `package ‘stringr’ was built under R version 4.1.2` when loading stringr 1.5.0.

Comment: @Canovice Can you update your R version as well.

Comment: yes I am to 4.2.3

Comment: @Canovice Your original code should also work with inserting the `=` between the `splitArr` and `\\[`

Answer (score 3):

We can combine the answers from @jay.sf and @akrun.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(fetch_url, "(?<=\\[)\\d+(?=\\])")
[1] "43"
```

This works with older `stringr` package.

If you need to extract a value for a specific argument you can include its name in look-behind parenthesis.

```
str_extract(fetch_url, "(?<=splitArr=\\[)\\d+(?=\\])")
```

Answer (score 2):

Lookbehind and -ahead.

```
regmatches(fetch_url, regexpr('(?<=\\[).*(?=\\])', fetch_url, perl=TRUE))
# [1] "43"
```